# How to increase RAM allocated memory in android studio arctic fox?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In previous versions of the android studio it was just follow this path:

Menu File => Settings => Appearance & Behavior => System Settings => Memory Settings

But in the arctic fox version it doesn't have the Memory Settings tab.

Comment: It's there for me in Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 - you can tap shift twice (or ctrl+shift+A) and type memory to get to it too

Answer (score -1):

Go to the last section of the android project, where you find build.gradle, and one of the files there has memory allocation, check them one by one...